# How to extract an area from osm?

Tags: r, openstreetmap, osmosis

using osmosis I want to extract all natural areas from an xml osm map

```
osmosis --read-xml map.osm --way-key-value keyValueList="natural" --write-xml out.osm
```

When reading the output map out.osm (using R and readOGR), this map contains only points, while I expected multiplepolygons.

natural <- readOGR('out.osm')

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There’s an SE GIS forum.

Comment: I want to do it in command line as a script

Comment: Then why is there an R tag?

Comment: Because I want then to be able to deal with it using R, and the issue may be linked to either the way I extract the layers, or the way I read them.

Comment: Neither you nor the single respondent is using R at least as the [r] tag is defined in the SO context. If there is a different “R” then a different tag should be created and properly defined.

Comment: The question is _mostly_ about osmosis, which is why I was able to answer it. I know nothing about R. Then again somebody might be able to answer it better, if you know more about the data that R and readOGR work best with.

Comment: In my issue, I had two components : osmosis and R, and was not sure, which one were responsible. As a consequence I have tagged both. It looks like the culprit was the osmosis extraction, but it could have been the way I then read the osm file with R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `--tag-filter` instead:

```
export INFILE=map.osm

osmosis \
   --read-xml $INFILE \
   --tag-filter accept-relations natural=* \
   --used-way \
   --used-node \
   \
   --read-xml $INFILE \
   --tag-filter reject-relations \
   --tag-filter accept-ways natural=* \
   --used-node \
   \
   --read-xml $INFILE \
   --tag-filter reject-relations \
   --tag-filter accept-nodes natural=* \
   --tag-filter reject-ways \
   \
   --merge \
   --merge \
   --write-xml out.osm
```

This gives you relations, ways, and also nodes (three separate streams which get merged)

If you're only interested in natural areas, then you don't want the individual nodes (e.g. individual natural=tree nodes) so you would do this:

```
export INFILE=map.osm

osmosis \
   --read-xml $INFILE \
   --tag-filter accept-relations natural=* \
   --used-way \
   --used-node \
   \
   --read-xml $INFILE \
   --tag-filter reject-relations \
   --tag-filter accept-ways natural=* \
   --used-node \
   \
   --merge \
   --write-xml out.osm
```

Not exactly sure what nodes you were seeing with your first attempt, but [the docs for --way-key-value](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.38#--way-key-value_(--wkv)) say that it's deprecated, and also "Note that this filter only operates on ways"

Comment: Looking at the map, it works as expected. I need the nature polygons, so I then just had to do a readOGR('natural.osm', 'multiplepolygons') after the 1st extraction you gave.

Comment: Question : why do you use twice the argument --used-node ?

Comment: Good question. That was mistake :-)  I have edited the answer to remove the duplicate --used-node bits. I guess it would've had no effect. There remains two --used-node bits in the overall command, but you can see the reason for that.